# Format phone number as you type (xxx) xxx - xxxx

Tags: javascript, regex, knockout.js, knockout-binding-handlers

I am writing a custom `bindingHandler` in `knockout` to format the (US) phone numbers in the following format as they type it.

> (xxx) xxx - xxxx

HTML code...

```
 <input type="text" data-bind="phoneNumber: phone" />
```

And binding handler...

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.phoneNumber = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element,valueAccessor, allBindings);
        },    
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var phone = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (!phone) return;
        var output;
        input = phone;
        input = input.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        var areaCode = input.substr(0, 3);
        var nextThreeDigits = input.substr(3, 3);
        var lastFourDigits = input.substr(6, 4); 

        if (areaCode.length < 3) {
            output = "(" + areaCode;
        } else if (areaCode.length == 3 && nextThreeDigits.length < 3) {
          output = "(" + areaCode + ")" + " " + nextThreeDigits;
        } else if (areaCode.length == 3 && nextThreeDigits.length == 3) {
          output = "(" + areaCode + ")" + " " + nextThreeDigits + "-" + lastFourDigits;
        }

        var phoneObs = valueAccessor();
        phoneObs(output);
    }
};
```

The following code works as expected. The one flow with this approach is ***deleting a phone number using `backspace`***. Once it deletes the last four digits and hits the `-` it can't delete the `-` nor `( )` since I'm dynamically adding the `-` and `( )` based on the length. I can use the arrow keys or click before those symbols and start deleting, or I can highlight the textbox and delete all at once. But I need to be able to remove the symbols by backspace or simulate and remove it from the code dynamically.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?

## UPDATE

Here's [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/132/). The only issue I'm having with this fiddle is it doesn't update the values on value change. It only updates if you press enter or leave textbox. Not sure If I'm missing anything else...

I have updated my logic to account for the issue I am experiencing, which is fixed. But I have noticed that both logic have one more issue.

If I have a phone number

(123) 456-7890

If I remove 1 from the area code, the cursor doesn't stay at the same place (before 2). It moves to the end of string and everything shifts one number down.

```
if (areaCode.length <= 3 && nextThreeDigits == "") {
    output = "(" + areaCode;
} else if (areaCode.length == 3 && nextThreeDigits < 3) {
    output = "(" + areaCode + ")" + " " + nextThreeDigits;
} else if (areaCode.length == 3 && nextThreeDigits.length <= 3 && lastFourDigits.length == "") {
    output = "(" + areaCode + ")" + " " + nextThreeDigits;
} else if (areaCode.length == 3 && nextThreeDigits.length == 3 && lastFourDigits.length <= 4) {
  output = "(" + areaCode + ")" + " " + nextThreeDigits + "-" + lastFourDigits;
}
```

Comment: Is there a jsFiddle we could fiddle with? ^^

Comment: @Whothehellisthat, I have updated the question and added jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about using an input mask (jasny has a nice one http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/ ) and a custom binding.

here is a fiddle where I did it.http://jsfiddle.net/vL59q8e1/2/

here is the javascript for the binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers.inputmask = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);

     $(element).inputmask({
        mask: '(999) 999-9999'
        });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
      }
};
```

Comment: This seems pretty interesting approach. I'm going to try it and let you know how it worked out for me. Thanks.

Comment: I like this concept, however, one issue that I have with this approach for which I haven't found a solution yet, is that if you don't enter the exact format phone numbers (10 digits), the incorrect phone numbers disappear. And I'll have no records of it. I still want to be able to grab the incorrect values.

Comment: did you figure out a way to capture the incorrect phone numbers? I played around with it a bit but never got a good solution

Answer (score 0):

The easy way out is to add the marks after there are enough characters such that the cursor is always touching a number. Because the text field adds those characters, you have that bug whenever you add non-numeric characters. For example, the bug you mentioned with the "-" also happens when you have only 3 numbers and try to delete one number (it deletes the space, and then adds the space back). eg: if 3 numbers, `(123` and it adds the ) after they type in the fourth.

The other way is to save the `input = input.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');` in a data field on the element and skip the entire output stage if the number didn't change. eg:

```
input = input.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
if(element.phone == input){ return; }
element.phone = input;
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. But how will this know the position of the cursor? If in the area code (123) I remove the 1, 2 and 3 shifts down and another number from next three digits become an area code.

Comment: It doesn't know the cursor. Browsers don't have that good of control over cursor position. It's possible, but will be much more complicated if you want to track cursor position while typing and deleting characters. wysiwyg editors implement it, but it's not something I can boil down to a stackoverflow answer.